# Turn a long data structure to a wide matrix structure

Tags: r, network-programming, igraph

I do have the following data structure...

```
      ID value

1   1        1
2   1       63
3   1        2
4   1       58
5   2        3
6   2        4
7   3       34
8   3       25
```

Now I want to turn it into a kind of dyadic data structure. Every ID with the same value should have a relationship.

I tried several option and:

```
df_wide  <- dcast(df, ID ~ value)
```

... have brought me a long way down the road...

```
   ID 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 39 40
1     1001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2     1006 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3     1007 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0
4     1011 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5     1018 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6     1020 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7     1030 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8     1036 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Now is my main problem to turn it into a proper matrix to get a igraph object out of it.

```
df_wide_matrix <- data.matrix(df_wide)

df_aus_wide_g <- graph.edgelist(df_wide_matrix ,directed = TRUE)
```

don't get me there...

I also tried to transform it into a adjacency matrix...

```
df_wide_matrix <- get.adjacency(graph.edgelist(as.matrix(df_wide), directed=FALSE))
```

... but it didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an edge between all IDs with the same value, try something like this instead. First `merge` the data frame onto itself by the `value`. Then, remove the `value` column, and remove all (undirected) edges that are duplicate or just points. Finally, convert to a two-column matrix and create the edges.

```
res <- merge(df, df, by='value', all=FALSE)[,c('ID.x','ID.y')]
res <- res[res$ID.x<res$ID.y,]
resg <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(res))
```